# Sammy Js and ajax not working in IE browser

Tags: javascript, sammy.js

I am using sammy js and ajax for my frontend.

for example 
URL: www.mysite.com/#/index

```
 (function($) {
        var app = $.sammy(function() {
            this.get('#/index', function() {
                init();
            });
        });

        $(function() {
            app.run()
        });
    })(jQuery);


function int(){
    alert('testing');
}
```

In firefox and chrome i am getting alert message, but in IE its not working and i am not getting any error also. Any can one help for me?

Comment: Which version of IE and which version of jQuery do you use?
How does the error look like?

Comment: I am using jquery http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js.

Comment: I am getting some error in IE8 browser  (function($) {

        var app = $.sammy(function() {
            this.get('#/index', function() {
                alert('tgggg');
            });
        });


        $(function() {
            app.run()
        });
    })(jQuery);                                                            object doesn't support this property or method.

Answer (score 0):

I am using IE11.  after navigating through 2 routes, when I click browser BACK, it goes straight back to the path having no hash sign appended.  In Chrome it works as expected.